# Postgres cast split string to double precision

Tags: postgresql, query

I have a cost column in my postgres db whose type is varchar. It stores the costs of each service a client gets in this format "KES 0.80". I am trying to sum up everything to get a cost breakdown.

This is how my query looks

```
select sum(cast(split_part("cost", ' ', 2) as double precision)) from send_log;
```

I am having a challenge casting the string to double precision so that i can get the sum.
This is the error i am getting

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
```

And if i try to cast into an integer i get this error

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for integer: "0.8000"
```

I am looking a better method to cast the string to double precision or advise on how i can format my query to get the total sum from the cost column. Any pointers or useful links will be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To provide a general answer to this question, I did the following (all the  code below is available on the fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=00da8024d97fe2e9e9624bc16d5d4a51)).

- Just a note before we start. This is a signal lesson about UI design. **NEVER, EVER** let users enter text (if at all possible)! For example, the currency, if there's a choice, have a dropdown - **don't** let users enter a three-letter code! Likewise with the amount - validate it:

1. validate it on data-entry at the **first** point of sale/contact - e.g. amount >= 0, correct number of decimal points, commas &c., no trailing or leading spaces...

**and**

2. validate on INSERTion into to the database (amount >= 0, formatting is not for the database - just store a number in a field of the appropriate type for your currency - leave any formatting to your app/Excel... enforce any other minimum and/or maximum constraints also. Put **as much** control into the table's DDL **as possible**. You could use `ON INSERT` triggers for even more control!

- The Golden Rule (of UI design) is that if you allow users the possibility of messing up, then they will find a way of doing so!
- Final word on this matter - store relevant datums together - the currency field in its own 3 letter code field - the actual amount in a DOUBLE PRECISION or REAL or whatever. Avoid `VARCHAR()/TEXT` fields with a mix of data.

Anyway now, down to brass tacks!

I created a sample table:

```
CREATE TABLE payment
(
  amount TEXT NOT NULL
);
```

and populated it with "data":

```
INSERT INTO payment VALUES
('KES 0.80'),             
('KES  0.80'),            
('KES .80'),           
('xyzKES 0.80'),          
('KES . 0.80'),           
('KES 0.80afasf'),          
('KES 0.80__asdfa'),
('KES 0.80..asdfasdf'),
('KES 0.8.0..asdfasdf'),
('KES 0.8.0..asdfasdf');
```

Then, the tidying up step uses the [`REGEXP_REPLACE()`](https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/regexp_replace/) function. The **key** thing about this function is to remember that the `'g'` flag is important - with it, **everything** that matches is replaced, without, only the **first** occurrence of the pattern is replaced!

```
SELECT
  REGEXP_REPLACE(amount, '[^0-9\.]+|\. +|\.0|\.{2,}', '', 'g')::DOUBLE PRECISION
FROM payment;
```

Result:

```
regexp_replace
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
0.8
```

It's not perfect, but should do the job adequately. If you're interested, you can check out the wreckage of my previous attempts [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3c4dbcf28563314bb10eb69e32d08a9d). I would urge you to check out regular expressions [here](https://www.regular-expressions.info/) - they are tricky as you will see if you check out my previous efforts. There are many other regular expression sites.

Answer (score 1):

> It stores the costs of each service a client gets in this format "KES 0.80".

This looks to be *two* data items stored in a *single* field.
That breaks very basic, Data Normalisation rules.

If this represents Currency and Value then you should store these in two *separate* fields (of the correct Data Types) and put the two back together again when you *retrieve* the data.

Doing so would *completely remove* the need for your current, casting exercise.

Comment: Unfortunately, i have no control of the database, but in the future i think its a good factor to consider in design

Answer (score 0):

Not all your rows contain exactly that format, some may have two spaces between "KES" and the value.  eg.:

```
ghp=> select sum(cast(split_part('KES  0.80', ' ', 2) as double precision));
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type double precision: ""
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that an empty string `''` isn't a valid number and thus the cast fails. One way to deal with this is to use `nullif()` to turn an empty string into a `null` value:

```
cast(nullif(split_part("cost", ' ', 2), '') as double precision)
```

Maybe even combine that with trimming leading and trailing spaces:

```
cast(nullif(trim(split_part("cost", ' ', 2)), '') as double precision)
```

But the correct solution to that problem is to split up the column into two columns as suggested by Phil W.

Comment: ifnull() ?   Your example code is correct though.